# Android TextView tween animation doesn't scale properly

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I can't seem to figure out this one. I'm working on an android project where I have created a tween animation that scales the TextView a number of times. My animation resource is defined as follows...

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <scale android:fromXScale="1" android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="2" android:toYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="0"/>

    <scale android:fromXScale="2" android:fromYScale="2"
        android:toXScale="1" android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="500"/>

    <scale android:fromXScale="1" android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toXScale="2" android:toYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="1000"/>

    <scale android:fromXScale="2" android:fromYScale="2"
        android:toXScale="1" android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="1500"/>

</set>
```

The `TextView` to which the animation is applied is defined in an xml layout resource file inside a `RelativeLayout` as follows...

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="@string/textView1Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow_color"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="20.0"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Then, the animation is initialized and loaded from an activity...

```
animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.textview_grow_shrink);
textView1.startAnimation(growShrinkAnimation);
```

I think the code explains the intention which is scaling the `TextView` from big to small and viceversa

#### The problem

While the animation does start and runs as intended it seems that scaling is out of proportion while the animation is running. The TextView seems to grow way too big out of the screen boundaries until the animation stops and the `TextView` goes back to its initial state.

I have no idea if the initial size of the text has anything to do with this weird behaviour. The `textSize` property is set to `36sp` through a value resource (`text_size_large`) set in the `dimens` resource file

#### Question

Has anybody had this problem before? Is it something obvious I'm missing? How can I get this to work as expected?

I've tried Googling using several keywords but the articles that popped up where slightly unrelated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of desperation looking for a solution I still don't know what was going wrong and I believe there was a combination of issues I was having:

1. starting the animation on the activity's `onCreate` method. Moving this operation to a `Handler`'s `postDelayed` fixed the scaling issue
2. I have the feeling the Animations API is buggy as many posts suggested

I resorted to using a single animation rather than using a set based on some article suggesting issues with animation sets...

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.9"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="700"
    android:startOffset="0" />
```